# Spring: annotation-config base-package

Tags: java, spring

In spring configuration `<context:component-scan>` supports a `base-package` attribute to limit it classpath search. However, `<context:annotation-config>` does not seem to have a similar attribute. What's more, component scan implicitly enables annotation config. However, that seems to mean that by enabling component scanning in *just one* package of the project I have to enable annotation scanning in the whole project. Is that true, and if so, can it be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `<context:component-scan base-package="com.org.pkg1"/>` doesn't imply that you are

> enabling annotation scanning in the whole project

It's true that `<context:component-scan>` also enables `<context:annotation-config>`. But the latter only allows the recognition of annotations in the already registered beans (no matter if they come from a scan or from XML).

Answering your question:

> Is that true, and if so, can it be avoided

No.

This is the official doc for annotation-scanning:

> Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes: Spring's
>   @Required and @Autowired, as well as JSR 250's @PostConstruct,
>   @PreDestroy and @Resource (if available), JAX-WS's @WebServiceRef (if
>   available), EJB 3's @EJB (if available), and JPA's @PersistenceContext
>   and @PersistenceUnit